# Crop a big picture into several small size pictures

Tags: gimp, crop

Is there a a way with GIMP editor to crop a big picture into several small equal sized pictures? So when all those small pictures connected in order would make a big picture.

Comment: I'm not sure GIMP is the right tool.  It's easy to do with ImageMagick: "convert big_image.png -crop 100x100 tile%04d.png"

Comment: For those finding this from a search: take a look at Image->Zealous Crop ("Autocrop unused space from edges and middle")!

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson You should make your comment an answer, it's fantastic! I knew about convert but had been using `-crop 256x256 +repage +adjoin` not realizing the last two are probably unnecessary.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

We can easily slice an image to subimages along predefined [guides](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-concepts-image-guides.html) using the [Guillotine](http://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-guillotine.html) tool:

1. Define *Image > Guides > New Guides (by Percent)* at 25% 50% 75% horizontal and vertical resp.

   [image]
2. Apply *Image > Slice using Guides* (in Gimp 2.8. *Image > Transform > Guillotine*) to slice into subimages:

   [image]

To export the images in ready to use HTML code we can alternatively use a *[Slice](http://docs.gimp.org/en/python-fu-slice.html)* python-fu script made for this purpose.

Comment: You can use *Guillotine* with any guide. I sliced an image into two unequal parts by playing with an appropriate horizontal guide and then split the image into an upper and a lower part along this guide.

Comment: @OlafDietsche: yeah the *Guillotine* tool is quite versatile... it's the OP who wanted equally sized slices.

Comment: Now if only exporting all images was a thing ...

Comment: @ThorSummoner it is a thing: https://gimpscripts.com/2015/03/save-all/

Comment: Note that this is "Image -> Slice using guides" in the latest software (and may be found in "Image -> Crop -> Guillotine" in other versions).

Comment: @OJW: thanks a lot for spotting this - corrected.

Comment: @BillyKerr: That site does not seem to exist, and though gimpscripts.net does, that page is not there.

Comment: @PJTraill - I posted that link over 3 years ago.

Comment: @PJTraill maybe try this link instead, looks similar, but I haven't tested it. https://antumdeluge.wordpress.com/2017/12/20/export-all-open-images-in-gimp/

Comment: @BillyKerr: Thanks, that is still there and gives me a few pointers to how to automate GIMP.

Answer (score 5):

As far as gimp goes, I have no idea how to make multi-page posters or slice image, but that answer was already given, so that's good.

---

Other options:

1. **[Poste Razor](http://posterazor.sourceforge.net/)**

   - [image]
   - I was curious, since this apparently has win, mac and linux versions.
   - It looks like source forge is down at the moment, so I had to google [Poster Razor mac](http://posterazor.en.softonic.com/mac), to download it. [Windows version can be downloaded here.](http://posterazor.en.softonic.com/)
   - It seems pretty damn good. Has pretty much everything you could ask for. Although when compared to other methods, it doesn't reeaaally offer anything that you can't live without ( except maybe the next feature below ↓ )
   - Overlap feature combined with the easiness of the application makes me wish I had known about this application before. Of course it's only beneficial feature if you don't want any gaps between your paper sheets.
   - One big minus <sub>*( but at the same time very irrelevant minus )*</sub> seems to be the very same overlap feature I just praised. If you want to get creative and leave gaps between the sheets of paper, you have to set overlap to zero, but that screws up the preview. Overlap seems to be the thing that visually divides your picture in the preview, so when you set that to 0, you can't see how many slices you got and what it looks like. It is easy to get around <sub>*( which is why I said it was irrelevant )*</sub>: Set small overlap ( like 1mm ), go to the next page and slice up that image aaand then come back to overlap and set it to 0mm again. So it's not a big deal.
   - This will definitely be the application I'm gonna use if, I want to make multi-page poster again.
2. **The first thought that came to mind was [Block Posters](http://www.blockposters.com/).**

   - Only downside being that 1MB file size limit.
   - I have used it, and it does work pretty nicely.
   - I believe there are other sites/applications like this out there.
3. **In older versions of [Acrobat Reader, there is "Tile large pages" option](http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/print-posters-banners-acrobat-reader.html).**

   - Modern versions have "Poster" tab in the Print window.
   - Has overlap feature, which is super useful if you don't want to leave gaps between your sheets of paper.
4. **Photoshop Slice tool.**

   - Right click the document  with slice tool and choose "Divide slice"
   - If you happen to have photoshop, this is pretty fast thing to do and semi handy because you don't have to leave the application to do some image editing.
5. **Image Magick.**

   - Off the top of my head I can't remember how, but it is doable.

Comment: Block Poster is awesome solution. Quickest, simplest yet with 1 mb limitation. 10 likes for listing out viable options with pros and cons.

Comment: Joonas, you definitely added great input here. Now, next part of challenge would be, (which I don't expect any tool does automatically, but just idea for creative minds) to have the pieces of cropped picture in standard sizes (like 4x6, 5x7,..) and in combination of both portrait & landscape. Possibly, GIMP script would do..

Comment: @KhuljaSimSim why would you want to mix portrait and landscape? Wouldn't that just result in image with atleast 2 uneven edges? ...and if you were to cut out the extras to make even edges, then why not do it in portrait _or_ landscape to begin with?

Comment: The whole idea is not just to have a big picture, but a big Art piece. Something out of the box. So with the small pictures tiled up together in landscape - portrait fashion would be like crossword puzzle with horizontal - vertical words with may be few black boxes. Getting the picture of what I'm trying to portray ?

Comment: @KhuljaSimSim I think I got it. I don't know about that gimp method, but photoshop slices should at least help to do something like that, because you can get as manual with it as you like.

Comment: I forgot to tell, I found a way in GIMP. It's not single button click though. Here is how I did: First, configured grids to like 100 pixels. Set my selection tool with constant aspect ratio size 600 x 400, and in settings: snap to grid (by default it is guide). Then, kept choosing individual tiles port/land, cmd+c > cmd+shitf+v. Chosen ones marked with some color to not forget, and moved to next. Yes tedious work, but I'm hoping my efforts would turn out to an extra ordinary art piece.

Comment: @KhuljaSimSim Alright. It does sound like photoshop slices might be a bit more convenient. I do realize you probably don't have photoshop, I'm just saying so that it's out there.

Answer (score 1):

See also the [ofn-tile](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/) script. It cuts a layer into tiles of equal size, and saves them to file using a user-defined name pattern.

Comment: Please make an edit to include the code instead of just a link to the site incase the link were to go down.