# How to explode image into multiple smaller images?

Tags: export

Say I have this kind of image:

[image: orig]

You can see the black areas are separated by transparent pixels. If I want to extract these into new images, I could select the area, copy, create new image from clipboard. That works, but is pretty slow when I have 50 areas on the image. Not to mention, error prone due to snappy selection.

[image: rectangle]
[image: circle]

Is there a way to do this easily in GIMP or any other editor? Is there a technical term for this image processing?

Answer (score 1):

The way I would go about this in GIMP:

- Use the fuzzy select tool (magic wand) to select the shape you need
- Go to Image > Crop to selection
- Export (ctrl-shift-e)
- Undo (ctrl-z), start over

This takes me about two seconds per shape. Of course, fuzzy select works best with flat object in a single colour. If you've got more complex forms, it might be a bit harder to do.

---

Alternatively, if the images are aligned along a grid, you could use one of the methods described [in this post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/30008/crop-a-big-picture-into-several-small-size-pictures).

---

**EDIT**: found a similar question over at superuser, seems the [accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/320221) over there is the one you're looking for if you really want to automate the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to do it in Photoshop using **Slices**. Basically you select the slice tool, drag a window on top of the areas you want to export, and use "Export to Web".