# How to cut along guides to form layers in an image

Tags: gimp, layers, guides

I have an image that I need to split up into multiple smaller tile pieces. Each tile piece should be in its own layer. While I could manually create each layer,  this would take a very long time, considering I'm working with almost 100 small tiles. If it helps, these tiles are square and of constant size (16x16 pixels).

I thought the guillotine tool from [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/30008/crop-a-big-picture-into-several-small-size-pictures) might help, and while it does cut along the guides, it creates new documents for each tile piece.

**Is there a tool built-in to GIMP similar to guillotine which allows me to cut the image in-place into layers?** I'm using GIMP 2.8.22.

Here are 2 images describing the process I'd like to replicate with a tool (the layer names are irrelevant).

[image: initial]

[image: final]

Answer (score 1):

If they are all the same size; you can avoid setting up guides. See the [`ofn-layer-tiles` script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/).

If you want to use guides, see the [`ofn-guillotine-layer` script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/).