# Gimp: multiply one photo into matrix (mosaic) of photos automatically (make several small size photos on page)

Tags: gimp

Maybe that is because I did not choose proper words for query, but I could not find via web-search how to do my task efficiently in Gimp. Here (on SE) I've found only [Crop a big picture into several small size pictures](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/30008/crop-a-big-picture-into-several-small-size-pictures), but that is not directly applicable. I need to make several small size photos to print for documents and idea is to multiply one photo into a matrix of photos on one page: to make same photo into a matrix side-by-side and top-to-bottom w/out empty space. I suppose the task is rather often made and most probably there is an easy and efficient way to do so in Gimp. How to do that?

ADDED: Graphical illustration:

1. original
   X
2. Result
   XXXXXX
   XXXXXX

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Can you share an image of what you are trying achieve?  Not sure I understand what you mean by "multiply one photo".  Do you mean you want multiple copies of one photo? Is *copy* and *paste as new layer* not working for you?

Comment: You should probably use imagemagic for this.

Comment: @Billy Kerr, I edited the question. Surely I can copy-paste, but don't I have in such case manually align all of copies? I want them to be automatically aligned.

Comment: @Billy Kerr, thank you for the answer! I did not thought of it as automation, now I've read much of Gimp functionality is via scripted plugins which is automation. And looks like `tiles` is the word I did not know to find the answer.

Comment: Yes, it's not obvious if you don't know the word! I'm glad the filter works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *Filters > Map > Tile*

Break the aspect ratio link icon so you can enter different values in the width and height independently.

Multiply the width and height by the number of images you want. Here I added *3 to the width, and *4 to the height - which calculates the tile size for 3 images across by 4 down.

Click OK

[image]